# Use grep to search for words beginning with letter "s"

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to use grep to look through a file, and find words starting with the lowercase letter "s". Snippet of the file:

```
sjpope   pts/2    161.133.12.95    10:21am 43.00s  0.13s  0.01s  man bc
rmschalk pts/3    161.133.9.147    10:22am  1.00s  0.10s  0.02s  vi testb
jntrudel pts/4    161.133.9.11     10:23am  2.00s  0.09s  0.00s  vi testb
tjbanks  pts/5    161.133.9.70     10:41am  8.00s  0.06s  0.04s  -ksh
```

I want the output to have line stating with "s".

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how did the output differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For all these that want to search for *words* starting with given letter not for *lines* this one-liner will do:

```
grep -E '\bs' file.txt # all words starting with s
grep -E 's\b' file.txt # all words ending with s
```

I know that this is non standard `grep` behavior (`\b` regex anchor that means word break is not in extended regular expressions standard) but it works on most modern systems.

Comment: To match any words starting with `space + s`, just use `grep -E "\ss"`, like `ls -al /etc/init.d/ | grep -E "\ss"`

Answer (score 9):

Try the following:

```
grep ^s file.txt
```

Comment: my previous comment "This doesn't works for curl html output (grep for stderr)" was wrong, apologies. I get blank lines from some xml outputs using curl and grep with a carrot, but not from all sources. Seems to be a text filtering issue with my sed expression.
Anyway, the regex example above works on words within a line so it does a "better" job, in my particular instance

Answer (score 8):

Using standard `grep` you can search *words* starting with s, using `\<` (start of word) and `\>`(end of word) regexp:

```
grep '\<[s][[:alpha:]]*\>' file.txt # Words starting with s
```

Also if you want to output the *lines* starting with s, you just have to use the `^` character:

```
grep '^s' file.txt # Lines starting with s
```

Answer (score 3):

Yo can use

> grep ^s file.txt

command to get list of all line starting from s character.

Answer (score 2):

please use the below command
grep ^s filename

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for a particular word/string in a line you can try the following. this will extract the whole word starting with s.

```html
grep -o '\bs\w*'
```

If you want to search within a file then you can try the following.

```html
egrep -o '\bs\w*' sameple.txt
```

If you want to save the result in a new file then you can try the following.

```html
egrep -o '\bs\w*' sample.txt > newsample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a regular expression? The `^` character will search from the beginning of the string. In your particular case, for example, if you want all results that start with a lowercase 's':

```
    cat file | grep ^s
```

or simply

```
grep ^s file
```